# PHP simpleXML – Access child element

Tags: php, api, simplexml, children

I have an xml file which I want to access using PHP:

**xml**

```
<entry_list version="1.0">

<entry id="hypocrite">
    <def>
        <dt>:a person who puts on a false appearance of 
            <d_link>virtue</d_link> 
            or religion
        </dt> 
    </def>
</entry>
```

I want to echo the entire contents of *dt*, how do I do so? If I use

```
$def = $entry_list->entry->def->dt;
echo $def;
```

then I get

```
a person who puts on a false appearance of or religion
```

Or in other words, the entire contents of *dt* apart from *d link*.

**tl;dr: I want to echo the entire contents of *dt*, including *d link* (positioned correctly).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
echo $def->asXml();
```

However it will print out `<dt>` and `</dt>` tags.

You will not notice them in your browser unless you use htmlspecialchars() when echo'ing.

Comment: Alas, my reputation is still too low for me to upvote.